# TypeError: 'int' type is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Why is there a subscription error when I'm working in a 2d array? I'm so confused. WHy is there a problem when i say intervals[i][0]. Thanks

```
 def insert(self, intervals: List[List[int]], newInterval: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        var = True 
        i = 0 
        while var:
            if newInterval[1] < intervals[i][0]:
                var = False #below interval 
            if newInterval[0] > intervals[i][1]:
                var = False #above interval 
                
            #overlap 
            if newInterval[1] >= intervals[i][0] or newInterval[0] <= intervals[i][1]:
                minval = min(intervals[i][0],newInterval[0])
                maxval = max(intervals[i][1],newInterval[1])
                intervals = intervals[:i] + [minval,maxval] + intervals[i+1:]
            #no overlap, keep progressing
            i = i + 1 
        return intervals
```

Comment: please add method call example that produced this error

Comment: Seems pretty clear that `intervals` is not a 2D array.  You're not checking the bounds.  Do you initialize it to `[]`?

Comment: Because `intervals[:i] + [minval,maxval] + intervals[i+1:]` doesn't make a proper 2d array.

Comment: Good spotting.  You need more brackets: `intervals[:i] + [[minval,maxval]] + intervals[i+1:]`.

Comment: Also, after you set `var = False`, your code will continue on to modify the list.  I don't think that's what you want.  I suggest you eliminate `var` altogether, make the loop `while True:` and use `break` in those if statements.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot index an array twice, or else u r indexing the element. That’s the error

Comment: No, it is definitely not the error.  If your list contains a list, then using two indexes is quite normal.